# Creating an android app using camera api

Tags: android-camera

I am new in android devlopment.
I am making a camera app i stuck at point i got so many solution already on net but my problem is not solve please help.
I am automaticly capturing the image and uploading this on server But i get all the image in landscape mode with correct orientation else are not in correct orientation. At time of preview my display is rotating right but image orientation of capture image is not right My code is

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

```
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.
    try {
        Camera.Parameters parameters= camera.getParameters();           
         parameters = camera.getParameters();            
        //camera.setParameters(parameters);             
        setCameraDisplayOrientation(Preview.this,0, camera, parameters);
        //camera.setParameters(parameters);
        parameters.getPictureSize();
        parameters.setPictureSize(w, h);
        parameters.getPreviewSize();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);            
        camera.startPreview();
        } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Cannot start preview", e);    
    }
}

public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
        int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera, Camera.Parameters parameters {android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
        new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
        }
        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
        } else { // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }
        //parameters.setRotation(result);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);           
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call parameters.setRotation with the right value, before calling camera.setParameters. This adjusts the orientation of the captured JPEG images, which is independent of the orientation of the preview display.

See the Android documentation for sample code for how to call setRotation() correctly:
[setRotation documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation(int))